# How can I further optimize this query or is there any other alternative?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with 37 million records (11 million duplicates) and I want to delete all the duplicate records based on three columns. Currently I have written a command to do so as below in laravel 7-

```
$oldUserStatsQuery = DB::table('user_stats_data')
        ->select('user_stats_data.id')
        ->leftJoin(
            DB::raw(
                '(SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM user_stats_data GROUP BY client_id, user_id, data_point_id) AS max_stats_data'
            ),
            function ($join) {
                $join->on('user_stats_data.id', '=', 'max_stats_data.id');
            }
        )
        ->whereNull('max_stats_data.id')
        ->orderBy('user_stats_data.id');

$oldUserStatsQuery
        ->chunkById($this->chunkSize, function (Collection $chunks) use (&$deletedCount) {
            $ids = $chunks->pluck('id')->toArray();
            $idsString = implode(',', $ids);
            DB::statement("DELETE FROM user_stats_data WHERE id IN ($idsString)");

            $deleteCount = count($ids);
            $deletedCount += $deleteCount;
            $this->info("{$deleteCount} rows deleted.. ({$deletedCount} in total)");
        }, 'user_stats_data.id', 'id');
```

This code took around 7 hrs alone for deleting just 780k records. 'user_id', 'client_id' and 'data_point_id' are already indexed. Is there any way I can further optimize this query or any other alternative in order to perform the deletion as quickly as possible ?

Comment: What does the execution plan for that query tell you about the performance? Maybe you need to add some indexes?

Comment: @NicoHaase I already have indexes

Comment: Please share the execution plan. Maybe the indexes are not used as expected?

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM user_stats_data t1
JOIN user_stats_data t2 USING (client_id, user_id, data_point_id)
WHERE t1.id < t2.id;
```

This ONE query will delete ALL rows which are duplicates by `(client_id, user_id, data_point_id)` except one duplicated row with maximal `id` value.

If you need in storing the row with minimal `id` then use `WHERE t1.id > t2.id`.

Comment: I have a table of 36 million records. How do you suggest we modify this in order to not cause any database related timeout or connection issue ?

Comment: @RishavJain If your table contains an index by `(client_id, user_id, data_point_id, id)` (or at least by first 3 columns) then the selection of the rows to be deleted must be fast. The most part of elapsed time is the deletion itself - and I doubt that you can improve it.